# Check if given string is a palindrome using stack

Tags: java, string, stack, palindrome

Folks,

I was recently interviewed and got a question on Palindrome.

> Given a string ( which might represent a date ), check if it's a
>   palindrome or not using Stack.

I tried to come up with solution, but he didn't like that.

Can anyone show me the code snippet for it in Java ?

Thanks

PS : This is not a homework, actual interview question.

Comment: post your solution that didn't work

Comment: Did *he* mention why he didn't like it?

Comment: Post the code snippet that you answered !

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PalindromeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "test";
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(input.charAt(i));
        }

        String reverseInput = "";

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            reverseInput += stack.pop();
        }

        if (input.equals(reverseInput))
            System.out.println("Yo! that is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("No! that isn't a palindrome.");

    }
}
```

Comment: For spaces and case sensitive String use `input = input.replaceAll("\\s","").toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 6):

The general idea of doing this with a stack is extremely simple. I don't have time to syntax and Java code, but this is the concept in pseudocode.

```
string s = "test"
for i=0 to s.length
stack->push(s[i])
```

This would push t->e->s->t from left to right. So the resulting stack would look like this:

TOP -> |t|s|e|t| <- BOTTOM

Now, since the LAST character of the string is on top, you just need to pop until the stack is empty and store it in a string. This will be the reverse of the original string. You can then compare this string with the original, and if it matches you have a palindrome.

In this case you would do:

```
while(pop != '')
string s += pop'd character
```

So you would grab t, then s, then e and finally the first t and have s = tset.
Comparing this to "test", it is not a palindrome.

Comment: Reviving an old post here. While this is a working method, it avoids the real reason you use a stack for this problem (and in fact doubles the work). Here it's just used to reverse the string and check for equality with the original, a problem that could be solved with a string reverse function that is builtin in nearly all languages. If this is a homework problem, your professor likely wants you to understand that pushing the first half of the characters and popping the second half, checking for character equality along the way, results in an empty stack if the string is a palindrome.

Comment: @JacksonH That is actually a better way to do this. I wouldn't have thought of that myself, but is a great example as to how there are multiple ways to do the same thing in programming. And of course, not all ways are as efficient as others. Kudos!

Comment: @Jackson H Doubling the computation time does not change the asymptotic computation time. In both cases it is linear

Comment: @JacksonH what about the scenario where the palindrome is of odd length? Like "1234321"

Comment: @HoldenNelson simply ignore the middle character if the string is of odd length.

Comment: @JacksonH right, makes sense. Is it possible to do this method in the case where you don’t know the length beforehand? Like if it’s a linked list.

Comment: @LetsGoBrandon "doubles the work" is exactly what I meant!

Comment: @HoldenNelson you could do one pass through the linked list to get it's size. If that's not allowed you could still do it but I think the space complexity becomes something like n^2/4 because you'd have to maintain separate stacks for every possible center character until enough characters have been pushed that it's definitely located before the center