# I can't figure out how to create palindrome and i can't output my stacks

Tags: java, palindrome

```
Program that implements stack to check if a given string is a Palindrome or nor.
```

The program should accept the String from the user and check whether the string is equal to its reverse with the use of the stack operations PUSH and POP.

here's what i got so far:

```
 import java.io.*;  
 import java.lang.*;  
 import java.util.logging.Level;  
 import java.util.logging.Logger;  

  class mystack {  
  DataInputStream get=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
  int a[];  
  int i,top=0,n,item,out;  
  void getdata()  
  {  
  try  
   {  
//user inputs to stacks
   System.out.println("Enter the limit");  
   n=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
   a=new int[n];  
   }   
  catch(Exception e)  
   {  
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
   }  
  }

  void push(int item)  
  {  
    if(top==n)  
    {  
      System.out.println("STACK IS FULL");  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    a[top]=item;  
    top++;  
    }  
  }

  void pop()  
  {  
    if(top==0)   
    {  
     System.out.println("STACK EMPTY");   
    }  
    else  
    {  
      top--;  
      out=a[top];  
    }  
    System.out.println(out);  
  }

  void display()  
  {  
    if(top==0){  
      System.out.println("STACK EMPTY");
    }  
    else  
   {  
   for(i=top-1;i>=0;i--)  
    System.out.println(+a[i]);  
   }  
  }  
  }

 class Stack  
 {  
   public static void main(String[]args)  
   {  
      DataInputStream get=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
  int ch = 0,t = 0;  
  mystack obj=new mystack();  
  obj.getdata();  
  To display stacks
    System.out.println("1.PUSH 2.POP 3.DISPLAY");  
     try {  
       ch=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
     } catch (IOException ex) {  
       Logger.getLogger(Stack.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
     }  
     while(ch!=4)  
     {  
       System.out.println("1.PUSH 2.POP 3.DISPLAY");  
  switch(ch)  
  {  enter code here
    case 1:  
      try{  
      t=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
      }  
      catch(IOException e)  
      {  
      }  
      System.out.println("value");  
       try {  
       t=Integer.parseInt(get.readLine());  
       obj.push(t);  
     } catch (IOException ex) {  
       Logger.getLogger(Stack.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
     }  
      break;  
    case 2:  
      obj.pop();  
      break;  
          case 3:obj.display();  
            break;  
  }  
 }  
   }  
 }
```

I can't figure out how to create palindrome and i can't output my stacks

Answer (score 2):

This should be in comments but don't have enough reputation.Check this Question [Check if given string is a palindrome using stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872031/check-if-given-string-is-a-palindrome-using-stack)

Comment: Luckily the upvotes you are getting from this answer mean that you soon will have :).