# Palindrome using stack

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

I wrote a palindrome using stacks in java. But, due to some reason while popping the stack the program is not working as expected. I have also tried using the top and iterate using this variable. Either ways it is not working.

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Palindromer {

Stack<Character> stack = null;
int top = -1;

public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack = new Stack<Character>();
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }

    System.out.println("value of top is " + top);
    String returnString = "";

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        returnString += stack.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(returnString);

    return returnString.equals(s);
}
}

public class PalindromeChecker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Palindromer palin = new Palindromer();
    if (palin.isPalindrome("BananaB")) {
        System.out.println("is palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not a palindrome");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't instantiate a new, empty `Stack` in your `for` loop...
Btw: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java).

Comment: wow thanks that works.

Comment: @WhiteViking no duplicate, the question your refer has very low quality.

Comment: @Wolf I referred to it because it poses the same question and has a correct answer, but you are right, the question itself was of poor quality. I deleted my comment.

Comment: I did not find the question very useful. Also, I wanted to know if there is any efficient way to check the string palindrome with less time complexity.

Comment: @WhiteViking Well, there is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17872271/2932052) that does it quite good ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `new Stack<Character>();` outside the loop.

The way you do it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack = new Stack<Character>();
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }
```

the `stack` variable is reassigned each loop and does contain only one character after the loop. Change it into

```
    stack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }
```

BTW: Better declare `stack` and `top` in the `isPalindrome` method. So you get rid of the error in `top` with further calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise the stack outside the loop  i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack = new Stack<Character>();
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }
```

should be

```
stack = new Stack<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below version of `isPalindrome` method, `Stack` object was getting instantiated in each iteration of loop and hence you were not getting the expected behavior.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    stack = new Stack<Character>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        top++;
    }

    System.out.println("value of top is " + top);
    String returnString = "";

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        returnString += stack.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(returnString);

    return returnString.equals(s);
}
```